# How to use ng-options and ng-model in an AngularJS custom directive

Tags: angularjs, directive, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-options

I'm trying to encapsulate some dropdown list from html code, here is my html code

```
<custom-dropdown function="foo" data="{{application}}" target="toBeUsedLater">                             
</custom-dropdown>
```

and here is my custom directive code for customDropdown:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('sample')
.directive('customDropdown', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        scope: {
            data: '@',
            function: '&',
            target: '@',
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            function insertList(obj) {
                var model = scope.function()(obj);

                const list = document.createElement('select');

                //here I want to set the ng-model to whatever target passed in
                list.setAttribute('ng-model', scope.target);     

                //model is a local var, I do not know how to make it work for ngOptions
                list.setAttribute('ng-options', "item for item in model")  

                element.append(list);
            }

            element.on('load', insertList(scope.data));
        }


    };
});
```

Basically I want to use ngOptions based off of a list that is created locally, and I want to assign the list an ngModel that is passed in as "target", in this case it is called 'toBeUsedLater'. The purpose is to use toBeUsedLater in some html code following the use of this custom directive.

I have tried to us a clumsier way:

```
 link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            function insertList(obj) {
                var model = scope.function()(obj);

                const list = document.createElement('select');
                list.setAttribute('ng-model', scope.target);

                //default option
                const option = document.createElement('option');
                option.setAttribute('value', '');
                option.textContent = '--Select--';
                list.append(option);

                for (let i of model) {
                    const option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.setAttribute('value', i);
                    option.textContent = i;
                    list.append(option);
                }

                element.append(list);
            }

            element.on('load', insertList(scope.data));
        }
```

This renders the list properly but still fails to assign "toBeUsedLater" as the ngModel. Preferably I want to use ngOptions because it is neat. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Just need to add  `template`  property to directive that has something like `'<select ng-model="target" ng-options="....">'` in it. If you create those elements yourself you have to use `$compile()` in order to bind to scope

Comment: @charlietfl doesn't template create a separate temporary html page rather then modifying the existing (parent) html page? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: No. A directive has `template` option that can be string html, or function that returns html or templateUrl can be remote file. See directive docs

Comment: @charlietfl well I think the ng-model part is not working, I get the [ngModel:nonassign] error. I tried both scope.target and target and neither worked. I think manipulating ng-model  outside the DOM is quite tricky.